# TemporaryDirectory() throws an attribute error when program runs

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am attempting to create a temporary directory using `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:`

I have imported tempfile

When I run the program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "batch.py", line 79, in <module>
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TemporaryDirectory'
```

I am running python 3.8

The program will run successfully if run with the debugger but when I run it without the debugger I get this error.

Comment: How do you know which version of Python you are running?

Comment: In the same directory as `batch.py` is there also a `tempfile.py` file? You need to rename that file if so.

Comment: The bottom left of my editor (VS Code) says I am running Python 3.8. I do not have any file in the same directory as batch.py with the name of tempfile.